# solve $xyy''+yy'-(x)^2(y)'^3=0$ by using reduction of order method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to set $$y'= p$$ $$y''=p.p'$$
$$xypp'+ yp-x^{2}p^3=0$$
$$\frac{xyp'}{p^2} +\frac{y}{p^2}=x^2$$
$$u=\frac{y}{p}  \rightarrow u'= 1-\frac{yp'}{p^2}$$
$$ \rightarrow x(1-u) + \frac{u}{p} =x ^2$$
I'm stuck in here and don't know what to do next. Am I wrong somewhere ? Can I get a hint or a solution for this problem? Thank you all!

Comment: The second line is wrong

Comment: Can you please give us a little more information, such as what the motivation behind the question is?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Iff $y'(x) = y' = p = p(y(x))$ then it's correct:
$$
\begin{align*}
y''(x) &= (y'(x))'\\
y''(x) &= (p(y(x)))' \tag{use chain rule}\\
y''(x) &= y'(x) \cdot p'(y(x)) \tag{use $y'(x) = p(y(x))$}\\
y''(x) &= p(y(x)) \cdot p'(y(x))\\
y'' &= p p'\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha finds a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5Bx+y%5Bx%5D+y%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+y%5Bx%5D+y%27%5Bx%5D+-+x%5E2+y%27%5Bx%5D%5E3+%3D%3D+0%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D):
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \frac{c_{2} - \ln\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( c_{1} \cdot \left( c_{2} - \ln\left( x \right) \right) \right)}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\operatorname{W}$ is the lambert W-function. There are also the trivial solutions $y\left( x \right) = \text{constant}$.

Comment: @KevinDietrich thank you i edited it

Comment: @KevinDietrich yes i did a search on wolfram too but i don't know how to lead to that solution.

Answer (score 4):

The trick to solve the equation is to rewrite it as an ODE for $x(y)$. Notice that$^{(*)}$
$$
\dot{x}:=\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{y'} \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\ddot{x}:=\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{y'}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{y'}\right)\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y''}{(y')^3}. \tag{2}
$$
Therefore, dividing the ODE $xyy''+yy'-x^2(y')^3=0$ by $(y')^3$, we obtain
\begin{align}
-xy\ddot{x}+y(\dot{x})^2-x^2=0 &\implies \frac{x\ddot{x}-(\dot{x})^2}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{y} \\
&\implies\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{y} \\
&\implies\frac{\dot{x}}{x}=-\ln y + c_1 \\
&\implies \ln x = -y\ln y + y+c_1y+c_2.\phantom{\frac{d}{dy}} \tag{3}
\end{align}
To express $y$ as an explicit function of $x$, let's first rewrite $(3)$ as
$$
y\ln y +C_1y=c_2-\ln x=:f(x), \tag{4}
$$
where $C_1=-(c_1+1)$. Now, let $u:=\ln y$; then
$$
f(x)=e^uu+C_1e^u=(u+C_1)e^u=e^{-C_1}(u+C_1)e^{u+C_1}. \tag{5}
$$
Using [Lambert W-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), we can rewrite $(5)$ as
$$
W(e^{C_1}f(x))=u+C_1=\ln y +C_1. \tag{6}
$$
Multiplying both sides of $(6)$ by $y$, and using $(4)$, we finally obtain
$$
y W(e^{C_1}f(x)) = f(x) \implies y=\frac{f(x)}{W(e^{C_1}f(x))}
=\frac{c_2-\ln x}{W(c_1'(c_2-\ln x))}. \tag{7}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ As @Kevin Dietrich remarked in one of his comments, $y(x)=\text{constant}$ is a solution to the ODE. In what follows, I'm looking for solutions $y$ such that $y'\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The method you are trying only works for autonomous DE of second order. But multiply the equation with $x$ and you have something that looks like a non-linear Euler-Cauchy equation, the number of $x$ factors in each term equals the number of derivations there.

So taking the idea for a parameter change from there, set $x=e^t$ and $u(t)=y(e^t)$. Then $u'(t)=e^ty'(e^t)=xy'(x)$ and $u''(t)=e^ty'(t)+e^{2t}y''(e^t)=xy'(x)+x^2y''(x)$. Inserting into the equation reduces it to
$$
u(t)u''(t)-u'(t)^3=0.
$$
This now is separable, divide by $uu'^2$ to get
$$
u'(t)^{-1}=\ln|u(t)|+c\\
u'(t)=\frac1{\ln(Cu(t))},~~~Cu(t)>0.
$$
Here it could have been useful to switch to $u'=p(u)$ to see the separable nature of the equation and find the integrating factor with less guessing.

Compare against
$$
(u\ln(Cu))'=(\ln(Cu)+1)u'=1+u'\\~\\
\implies Cu(t)\ln(Cu(t))=Cu(t)+Ct+D
$$
If one sets now $Cu(t)=\exp(v(t))$, this looks closer to the Lambert-W function, that is, its definition via the inverse.
$$
e^v(v-1)=D,~~e^{v-1}(v-1)=(Ct+D)e^{-1},~~ v(t)=1+W((Ct+D)e^{-1})
$$
Now substitute backwards, discuss which branch of the Lambert function gives what domain for the solution etc.

Comment: Thank you very much